# Installing root certificate in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, certificates

I followed this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html) until the end at the end it says `copy everything beginning with the line: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and continuing through the line: ----END CERTIFICATE----- lines to a file named after the hostname of the server where the certificate will be installed.`

Then I tried [this](https://wiki.wmtransfer.com/projects/webmoney/wiki/Installing_root_certificate_in_Mozilla_Firefox) with the just mentioned file I get `this is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can't be imported into the authority certificate list.`
 Could you please help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial help you create *Creating a Self-Signed Certificate*.

Firefox required the certificate to be signed by authorized authority.

In order to avoid the error you got, you can add the certificate as authorized authority.

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/firefox-adding-trusted-ca/) you can find how to do it (with updates to up-to-date version of Firefox):

- Open Firefox
- Preferences
- Advanced
- Certificates
- View Certificate
- Authorities
- Import
- Provide the certificate